# Automatic Node Categorization not working in OpenNMS

Tags: monitoring, network-monitoring, opennms

I setup a Node Categorization policy in the foreign source definition ; its not working correctly what changes need to be done?

[image]

Text version: (for bot/crawler)

```
name SetNodeRouter      class org.opennms.netmgt.provision.persist.pollicies.NodeCategorySettingPolict
    key category              value Router
    key matchBehavior         value ALL_PARAMETERS
        key sysObjectId value .1$
```

Please do let me know if something wrong with the config and any extra info I could provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist you need a ~ at the beginning of that value to tell OpenNMS this is regular expression and not a literal string match. Second, it seems you are wanting to match any string that ends in .1 so:

```
"~.*\.1$"
```

is what you need.

Comment: Without quotes? and a should i delete and re add all the nodes so that they can pick up their node categories?